# Anaconda-navigator has many unknown strange green circles

Tags: anaconda, navigator, fault

navigator has been displaying these green circles for some time and I can't seem to get rid of them. Could you please advise me how to get rid of them or why they are there? I have the latest version of the navigator 1.10.0 and of conda 4.9.1. I also have updated all packages with `conda update --all`. I do not have any other environments.

[image]
Thank you so much,

Comment: Applications without their own icon get the Anaconda icon. Anything with an "Install" button is shown as a suggestion, e.g., some packages others frequently install.

Comment: Thank you @merv, my colleague has exactly the same version and does not have any suggestions. I also do not want to see them, is there a way to get rid of these green circles? Im happy to keep the others with an icon.

Comment: Okay. I don't know if that is possible or why there is a difference. Sorry I could not be more helpful.

Comment: Attempting to disable the green circles using the cog wheel, did not work for me. I ended up following troubleshooting guide on Anaconda website. Uninstalled Anaconda-Navigator, re-installed and re-set it. Now I only have 1 extra green circle. Not ideal, but an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. A bunch of unneccery packages were shown in my Anaconda Navigator. Are you using other channels to download/install packages? For example, conda-forge and so on. I have solved this kind of problem by removing conda-forge channel from my list of used channels.

[My Anaconda Navigator with conda-forge channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzeGk.png)

[My Anaconda Navigator without conda-forge channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4z4Z.png)

The following answer was very helpful in solving the problem: [Anaconda showing too many packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67643367/anaconda-showing-too-many-packages)