# Anaconda showing too many packages

Tags: user-interface, anaconda, package, navigator

I was messing with Anaconda this morning and making a new environment in the command prompt.  After doing that Anaconda Navigator started showing multiple packages such as anypytools, dioptas, fsleyes, gnuradio.  I suppose these need to be on the computer, but I don't want to see them on the Navigator screen.  How can I not show them?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by:

1. Navigate to `Channels` which are on top of `Home` in the `Navigator`
2. Click the `Trash-Button` of `conda-forge` (already deleted in my picture).
3. Update channels.

[image]

For me the problem occured after using: `conda config --set channel_priority strict` in the anaconda prompt. To reset this you can use: `conda config --set channel_priority true`.